# alphanumeric row stored as text excel 2007

Tags: excel

I have a column stored as text, this column is mainly full of numeric codes with leading zeroes I need.  Is there a way to highlight all cells in one fell swoop if they contain letters (even though everything is being stored as text)?  I know I can do conditional formatting for every letter and highlight the cells, I was just hoping there was a single, quick solution to finding letters in and amongst numerals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do the conditional formatting for the first cell;
2. Copy the cell;
3. Special Paste the cell on all the cells you want to apply the conditionnal formatting;
4. Select "Formats" to only paste the conditionnal formatting.

The formula you'll want to apply in step 1:

```
 =ISTEXT(*select your first cell*)
```

Or if your Excel application is in french:

```
 =ESTTEXTE(*select your first cell*)
```

Comment: I..I can't believe I've ever noticed this before.  Well done. this still involes conditionally searching for every letter, though, right?

Comment: no you can use a formula in the conditionnal formatting (I'll edit my answer)